# $this->Auth->login() not defined

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I'm getting Error: Call to undefined function login() when i
debug($this->Auth-login());

when i click login in my members login it goes to "user/login" page
I once had UserController but now i deleted it.

Member model:

```
    App::uses( 'AppModel' , 'Model' );
App::uses('SimplePasswordHasher','Controller/Component/Auth');
class Member extends AppModel {

public function beforeSave( $options = array() ) {
if( isset( $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] ) ) {
$passwordhasher = new SimplePasswordHasher();
$this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordhasher->hash( $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] );
}
return true;
}
}
```

MembersController:

```
public function login() {
if( $this->request->is('post') ) {
debug($this->Auth-login());

if( $this->Auth->login() ) {
return $this->redirect( $this->Auth->redirect() );
}
$this->Session->setFlash( __( 'Invalid username/password' ) );
}
}
```

login.ctp

```
<div class="users form">
<?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Member'); ?>
<fieldset>
<legend>
<?php echo __('Please enter your username and password'); ?>
</legend>
<?php
echo $this->Form->input('username');
echo $this->Form->input('password');
?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Login')); ?>
</div>
```

Here is my AppController:

```
public $components = array(
'Session',

'Auth' => array( 
'loginRedirect' => array(
'controller' => 'members',
'action' => 'profile'
),
'logoutRedirect' => array(
'controller' => 'members',
'action' => 'index'
)
),

'DebugKit.Toolbar'

);
```

I want to redirect to members/profile page after members/login

Comment: `Form->create('Member')` You cannot use the namespace "Member" when the Auth component still expects the default "User" etc. You need either stick to "User" or make all involved components aware of the changed Model name.

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to use `Member` model rather then default `User` model, you should let Cakephp know about that like-

```
public $components = array(
                        'Session',
                        'Auth' => array(    
                            'loginRedirect' => array(
                                'controller' => 'members',
                                'action' => 'profile'
                            ),
                            'logoutRedirect' => array(
                                'controller' => 'members',
                                'action' => 'index'
                            ),
                            'authenticate' => array(
                                'Form' => array(
                                    'userModel' => 'Member'
                                )
                            )
                        ),
                'DebugKit.Toolbar'
);
```

Comment: Is there any other default model Like User? I always hav to mension model like above?

Comment: its not working even i put 'userModel' => 'Member'. In beforeFilter i have allowed index and view . **I dont know Where i have to give this beforeFilter**

Comment: There is a typo mistake on your `debug($this->Auth-login());`. You miss `>`.. This must me `debug($this->Auth->login());`.. Well, you are right about `beforeFilter`.. And You said not working.. Is there any error message? Show your database schema of `members` table..

Comment: even i change userModel in appcontroller component it member/login redirect to user/login. There is no erro msg. where can i put Auth-allow() in other than beforeFilter